# how to pass variable from chrome.tabs.create

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

i am new in chrome extensions development,
i am going to create a simple extension in which when the main button pressed chrome pass the current open tab's URL to my website,
but the problem i can't understand how to pass javascript variables from chrome.tabs.create method??

my mainfest.json file:

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "Fake URL Detection",
"description": "Detect the fake URL when you access it from your browser.",
"version": "1.0",

"permissions": [ "contentSettings", "tabs" ],

"browser_action": {
"default_icon": "icon.png"
},

"background": {
    "scripts": [
        "background.js"
    ]
}
}
```

my background.js file:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {

chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
    var tabId = tab.id;
    var tabUrl = tab.url;

    alert(tabUrl);
});
chrome.tabs.create({
    url: "http://mywebsite.com/search?q="+tabUrl
});
});
```

please help me,
how can i pass that tabUrl variable to my external URL

Comment: Declare tabUrl variable in global context

Comment: is in mainfest file???
can you please give me an example?

Answer (score 4):

Why are you trying to pass the `tabUrl` variable to `chrome.tabs.create`? You can call the `tab.url` information in the `chrome.tabs.create` method.

**background.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.create({
        url: "http://www.google.com/search?q=" + tab.url  //Changed the URL for testing
    });
});
```

Comment: The global variable declaration would work as well, but I can't think of a reason why you would want to do that for such a simple extension.

Comment: @TrojanHorse if this works for you, please accept the answer to help others with the same question find it quickly.